# Html to image not working in semi circle chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I am trying to convert html div into image. I have a semi circle chart but when I am trying to download or preview image the image is not proper . Please help.
I took the reference of these two sites : 
for semi circle : https://codepen.io/vineethtr/pen/xGjQOX
for html to image : https://codepedia.info/editor-example/jquery-convert-html-to-image-example/

Please help me to get the same exact image.

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

  $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
  });

});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>CodePen - Semi Circle Donut Charts</title>
<style>
body {
  background: #1F2428;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
}

.margin {
  margin: 25px;
}

.semi-donut {
  --percentage: 0;
  --fill: #ff0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: var(--fill);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.semi-donut:after {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 50px solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) var(--fill) var(--fill);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( -45 + var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
          transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( -45 + var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
  -webkit-animation: fillAnimation 1s ease-in;
          animation: fillAnimation 1s ease-in;
}

.semi-donut-model-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: var(--fill);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.semi-donut-model-2:before, .semi-donut-model-2:after {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 50px solid var(--fill);
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%  0% 0;
          transform-origin: 50%  0% 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.semi-donut-model-2:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.semi-donut-model-2:after {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: 1s fillGraphAnimation ease-in;
          animation: 1s fillGraphAnimation ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
          transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
}
.semi-donut-model-2:hover:after {
  opacity: .8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.multi-graph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.multi-graph:before {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%  0%;
          transform-origin: 50%  0%;
  border-radius: 300px 300px 0 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.multi-graph .graph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 50px solid var(--fill);
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%  0% 0;
          transform-origin: 50%  0% 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 300px 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-animation: 1s fillGraphAnimation ease-in;
          animation: 1s fillGraphAnimation ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
          transform: rotate(calc( 1deg * ( var(--percentage) * 1.8 ) ));
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multi-graph .graph:after {
  content: attr(data-name) " " counter(varible) "%";
  counter-reset: varible var(--percentage);
  background: var(--fill);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(calc( -1deg * var(--percentage) * 1.8 )) translate(-30px, 0px);
          transform: rotate(calc( -1deg * var(--percentage) * 1.8 )) translate(-30px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
          transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.multi-graph .graph:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.multi-graph .graph:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 30px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fillAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
            transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fillAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
            transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillGraphAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes fillGraphAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
</style>

  <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

  
  
  <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>


</head>

<body translate="no" >
  <div class="semi-donut margin" style="--percentage : 80; --fill: #039BE5 ;"  id="html-content-holder" >
  HTML5
</div>
 <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP?

Comment: You should also explain what _"the image is not proper"_ means? Please post an example of the expected result and what you're currently getting. We're not there with you and don't have any clue what you're trying to accomplish. We're 100% dependent on you to inform us in your question.

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. Then, explain what the actual problem is. “Not propper” is not helpful in that regard.

Comment: Note that the `<br>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML and never have.